# pdfplumber - How to extract table with no horizontal lines?

Tags: python-3.x, text-extraction, pdfplumber

So I have a table like this one, with an unknown number of description lines. Some can have 1, 2, 5, even zero, or more lines:

[image]

(I removed all sensitive informations.)

and I use :

```
with pdfplumber.open("invoice.pdf") as pdf:
   pages = pdf.pages
   for page in pages:
      page.extract_table()
```

which is does extract all data from the table but the second column it treats as one row.
**I want somehow to split the lines of second column** (or better all columns) **by a small blank row**, which so I put it on red rectangles to highlight it.

I know that I need to use `table_settings={}`, but I can't figure out ... yet, which property (ies), to use ?

What I tried:

```
print(page.extract_table(table_settings={
                    "horizontal_strategy": "text",
                    "snap_y_tolerance": 3,
                    "keep_blank_chars": True,
                }))
```

Which, again, it splits when he wants ..

So it's possible to extract a mix-borderless table ?

Comment: Hi, did you figure out any solution to this?

Comment: Unfortunatelly no. I opened an issue on the app itself. The discusion you can find it here : https://github.com/jsvine/pdfplumber/discussions/736

Comment: In short, They had an option settings for this, however it didn't helped as I had to manually hard code every white space line, and I couldn't find a single value that helped me.
Eg. It varied from 9 to 14. If I choose to small, breaks when I don't want. If I choose too much, it consider it as one line.

Comment: Yes, same here. In my case, I used `snap` to tie closer rows and blank line to separate each blocks. Luckily, it worked.